# Making first letter capital using regex like in ucwords

Tags: java, php, regex

I need to convert a String value in to Upper case (First letter to upper in every word).
This can be done in php by using ucwords() method.

Ex :

```
String myString = “HI GUYS”;
myString = myString. toLowerCase().replaceAll(“Regex”, “Some Charactor”)
```

Thanks with hi5

Comment: You wabt to do this in JAVA or Javascript? There is a big difference.

Comment: I want this in Java. Not in JS. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry hwnd. I didn't get you. I just want is to convert above myString to every first character capital in every word with java and regex. What should i use in replaceAll() method ? or should i use a different way? But i want to do this by using regex.

Comment: `Regex` is just a "regular expression". It is used to find / match specific characters, strings, etc. by itself it does not do substitution - for that you need to "match and replace". In this case, "match the first character of every word", and "replace with the capitalized version". Regex itself does not "do" replacement. As such your question is poorly phrased. It is a bit like "I want a screwdriver for this nail", when really what you want is "drive this nail into the wood", and the solution is "hammer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undermentioned will work great in all your situation

```
If you need to get first letter of all words capital ..
-----------------------------------------------------



 public String toTheUpperCase(String givenString) {
            String[] arr = givenString.split(" ");
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(arr[i].charAt(0)))
                        .append(arr[i].substring(1)).append(" ");
            }
            return sb.toString().trim();
        }



When you need first letter of first word to be capitalized 
-------------------------------------------------------------


public String toTheUpperCaseSingle(String givenString) {
                String example = givenString;

                example = example.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                        + example.substring(1, example.length());

                System.out.println(example);
                return example;
            }
```

How to use :: Try defining this code n your super class ( Best code practice )

Now when u need to use this method .. just pass String which you need to transform .
For Ex:: Let us assume our super class as CommanUtilityClass.java ...

Now you need this method in some activity say " MainActivity.java "

Now create object of super class as :: [ CommanUtilityClass cuc; ]

Final task -- use this method as described below:

```
your_text_view.setText(cuc.toTheUpperCase(user_name)); // for all words 

your_text_view.setText(cuc.toTheUpperCaseSingle(user_name)); // for only first word ...
```

Let me know if you need more details for that ..

Enjoy

Cheers !

Comment: Thanks for shearing..this is great.. can use in any place.

Comment: Got it and thank. Making a global utility class should be the answer with above methods.

Answer (score 3):

Using `regex`, it will be difficult. Try following simple code:

```
String str="hello world";
String[] words=str.split(" ");
for (String word : words) {
   char upCase=Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0));
   System.out.print(new StringBuilder(word.substring(1)).insert(0, upCase));
}
```

#### Output:

Hello World

Comment: Hm.. yeah.. I tried but make me sick. Using regex for this is little hard. String handling is the answer. Thank mate!

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(ucWord("the codes are better than words !!"));// in main method

private static String ucWord(String word) {
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    char[] c = word.toCharArray();
    c[0] = Character.toUpperCase(c[0]);
    int len = c.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        if (c[i] == ' ') {
            i++;
            c[i] = Character.toUpperCase(c[i]);
        }
    }
    return String.valueOf(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordUtils from apache for same purpose,

```
WordUtils.capitalizeFully(Input String);
```

Comment: Got it. Using a third party APIs are okay for some cases. But i am more prefer doing it in pure Java. Thank mate! This is useful.

Comment: You can write a utility method, that can format string manually.

Comment: Got it. Static utility class can be use as a global string hanler of the application. above api is also valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Here are simplified versions of the toUpperCase methods.

Change all first letters in the sentence to upper case.

```
public static String ucwords(String sentence) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (CharSequence word: sentence.split(" "))
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0))).append(word.subSequence(1, word.length())).append(" ");

    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

Change only the first word to upper case. (nice one-liner)

```
public static String ucFirstWord(String sentence) {
    return String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0))).concat(word.substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String stringToSearch = "this string is needed to be first letter uppercased for each word";

```
    // First letter upper case using regex
Pattern firstLetterPtn = Pattern.compile("(\\b[a-z]{1})+");
Matcher m = firstLetterPtn.matcher(stringToSearch);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()){
    m.appendReplacement(sb,m.group().toUpperCase()); 
}
m.appendTail(sb);
stringToSearch = sb.toString();
sb.setLength(0);

System.out.println(stringToSearch);

output:

This String Is Needed To Be First Letter Uppercased For Each Word
```